# Create detail page from forEach using Firestore data

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, foreach

I already have a forEach showing an image and name this is clickable and takes you to a page ../page/details.

Once you click on that page (which would be the same page for all images and names) I want to then load the specific data with that document clicked on from Firestore.

I understand I would need to probably create an identifier and then show that in the detail page so it knows what was clicked (im able to do this in swift), but as models aren't used in JS how do I allow it to understand which content it should show.

As all images and names would be going to the same detail page would their also be a way to add the random doc id to the url so it would look something like ../page/details/Djf73Dhr7W8sJie6c3H9

Code to fetch the forEach and clickable detail page

```
 const i = query(collection(db, "teams"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(i, (querySnapshot) => {
            const teams = document.querySelector('.teams');

            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const docData = doc.data();
                const team = teams.appendChild(document.createElement('teams'));

                team.innerHTML = `
                <a href="../page/detail.html">
                    <h1 class="team-names"></h1>
                </a>    
                <div class="team-line"></div>
                <img class="team-image">
                `;
                team.children[0].textContent = docData.ageGroup;
                team.children[2].src = docData.teamImage;

                console.log("Current data: ", docData);
            });
        });
```

Where I show the forEach

```
<div class="teams">
    </div>
```

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/66221407/15774176..Is it helpful?

Comment: This kind of works, but how do I get to show the details parts on the next page e.g. you click the title and it takes you to another page where the main text would be. I can't seem to find that with the link you added

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: I resolved this setting a parameter as the doc id then fetching that on the next page to show the other content.